# Adblok запускает вкладку в браузере Firefox

Tags: firefox

При старте браузера Mozilla Firefox (68.0.2) постоянно открывается новая вкладка moz-extension://f3277ddd-d202-4b9b-9b1f-d318cf395632/first-run.html
с информацией о Adblock Plus. Можно ли убрать открывание этой новой вкладки не удаляя расширения Adblock Plus?

Comment: Та же проблема - надоедливое открытие вкладки moz-extension://abfbf8f4-0bd2-492b-bdea-054f1fd1d441/first-run.html в каждом начале работы с браузером FireFox